# Getting error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:80: bind: address already in use. while trying to map https to container port

Tags: linux, docker, https, containers, rhel8

Error: starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:80: bind: address already in use.

I am trying to access my container via https
currently, my httpd service uses both 443 and 80
I have a docker containers running in RHEL
When I try to map 80/443 host : 80 docker container …
I am getting error as Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:80: bind: address already in use.
Not sure what mistake I am making here
Please advise

tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:443 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 2313625/httpd
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 2313625/httpd

if I kill this process then I am unable to access the domain using https